# Typescript generic argument comparison

Tags: typescript

So there's this piece of code at the end of Typescript's [generics guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

```js
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean = true;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string = 'abc';
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number = 123;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper = new BeeKeeper();
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper = new ZooKeeper();
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    return new c();
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;   // typechecks!
```

This program just creates some classes and then defines a method that creates an instance of a given class. A problem arises when we try to do comparisons with variable `c` though. For example, if we want to check whether `c == Lion` then Typescript throws an error([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCm8DSiAO8BO0DeAoaB0AFpALKQDWAXNAEYD29I8YAdtALzQAuGArvADcuAL65coSDABajFPHRY8haKzABbeNzABzGhF4BLVjs7QA5GFrBzwsRPBRoAQVaH1YEDnyFWfdQAy8DoQNH7qtJhmAIwATADMduKSTgjw0PAAHtzwrAAmMK7unt4qFGiYNGnyimas8ADucIg1mAAUAJRJDlLQAYb07Fk5+YVuHl7KhOUKldCy9K1YXPVNC0ud3QBmfKzA3APswBgsOQCSrAZswPAAPM4Z2bkFLuOeAHxtwGGN0J2c7xcHRoDymBEMWy+nC4-UGHVKKkIAHokdA8vRoBB6JpuERjDofAQxCoTtw+Bh2KtoMBNqJkicwOdLto9vA2rDWB0AHQzRRctQ43SCAgongAT3QwCI8GAFAgAEIJAymVdWW00tzeZguSQIOQIBRhSLUdwJTLpbKFUA)). Anyone know a way to do such comparisons while still keeping type checking in place?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `keeping type checking in place`? What do you intend to do when you know that the constructor has a specific type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

It would look something like this:

```
type Constructor<T extends {} = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function typeGuard<T>(o: any, className: Constructor<T>): o is T {
  return o === className;
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: Constructor<A>): A {
    if (typeGuard(c, Lion)) {
        return new c('Lion initialized')
    }
    return new c();
}
```

Also please note the usage of `Constructor<A>` - you've mention that your constructors would receive parameters based on type - this can't be achieved by your implementation because your constructor definition doesn't receive any parameters and therefore you should use `Constructor<A>` to pass any number of parameters to constructor (it's up to you to pass correct arguments to correct type constructors).

Taking all that into account, I'd suggest a much cleaner and simpler approach. First define map of keys and corresponding types that can be created:

```
type TypeMap = {
    "lion": Lion,
    "bee": Bee
}
```

Then just create factory function which would suggest possible arguments ("lion" | "bee") on invoke, show error if unknown argument is entered and resolve correct return type.

```
function createSimpleInstance<T extends keyof TypeMap>(c: T): TypeMap[T] {
    let instance: Animal;
    switch (c) {
        case "lion":
            instance = new Lion("Lion initialized");
            break;
        case "bee":
            instance = new Bee();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown type");
    }
    return instance as TypeMap[T];
}
```

Great benefit of this is that within `createSimpleInstance` you are creating exact instances of `Lion` and `Bee` which helps you with autocomplete of exact arguments thats needed for each constructor function.

Please see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCm8DSiAO8BO0DeAoaB0AFpALKQDWAXNAEYD29I8YAdtALzQAuGArvADcuAL65coSDABajFPHRY8haKzABbeNzABzGhF4BLVjs7QA5GFrBzwsRPBRoAQVaH1YEDnyFWfdQAy8DoQNH7qtJhmAIwATADMduKSTgjw0PAAHtzwrAAmMK7unt4qwPSsBvzA3PQYABQAlKUqhBB8ik3CrYTllUzwAHQg9Dr15pHpxobchp6GAF7weeaN3YRiKhRomDRp8opmrPAA7nCIB5hdosmOMAGGFRnZuQUubh5eyr0VVXw1dXqADdPPojCZmt8eu1OmsfD0+hABsNRsDPHCVJtCNsFLtoLJ6JcsFxjmcCUTrvZuABPdDQADCv14-1qGAAPAAVZ45fIwbAiMz8gB8R1O0Hqg0lYAwIRobGpAG0ALrNDgijnCXAAMz4rBqj3YNPQAHE+NK8pyhfV6HLWNSADTQFIQAByGngNEZlWZAPZHKFjRo9GghhgXO+GC0fAw7GDHHjTrubs0SW1uv1T2AkbAOQAkt62MB4GznNzXoUPp4rcBPUzqqySwGaKWoSGteKjfBTeb6sBHQ8Ko1IfDWpHuNH2KSneMB+xprN5ksVo0R1iCGOJ6oxcBKeJO9AObT4ORUIKRwAiEAG880Wf2i+TG-neA3NN62aZ7M5ADK7lQzHzAxC2LLksh5N5tmpeh20PdAT2rGgOUDA8jxPBUOSVFoCGYbgQwLPUPXeYoQHWAgIBOGZgCIcVgGHHoCGASB0kva8qBHei8KAgjRTOWd6nPWc8JmOYryXc8MQ4whaGzChSNaRiIGYx82MkwhjC4oseOfa5VIIaSWFk9jCDyeAtTAPgQG4FTdO4IgMHoM4pwAUQweyGnPABVVgKFYBzDSPcS5LXaANxjTjtG4yAULgsBUHQpVUyzFg83wot6lnRpBhxRRBjUTRtB0QQCAAemKngjyo+BgAoCAAEIJC-eBAIitK0ky7LMEGEgIHICBZMIUryvQSrqrq5JGt-dR-ya1L4H4q8KnErKdgwXL3QKoroEGzsRpq+qkpzeBJum5rgP4x92pWrqyEoTatrKnaiCqvbxuSo6-wA2b+KRfKiGMHQlo61but6-qSrK4wQSvPJaqAA).

Answer (score 2):

You can check this with `if(c === instanceof Lion)`

Example:

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean = true;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string = 'abc';
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number = 123;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper = new BeeKeeper();
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper = new ZooKeeper();
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    const newInstance = new c();
    if(newInstance instanceof Lion) {
        console.log('Im a Lion');
    }
    return newInstance;
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;   // typechecks!
```

Hope this works and have a nice day :)

Comment: Hello! Your solution does work but involves creating an instance of `c`. We do not know what constructor arguments `c` take and thus this answer is invalid. I am looking for a way to do this without creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following? 
 `if(c instanceof Lion) {` 
 
Hope i understand your questions correctly.

Comment: This does not work. `c` is not an instance of `Lion`, but `Lion` itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to do this without creating an instance of the class.

Simple and works:

```js
function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    const lion: typeof Lion = Lion;
    if (lion.toString() === c.toString()) {
        console.log("Lion detected")
    }
    return new c();
}
```